# Button disabled and ngIf work on same condition

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I created a Material dialog and I call the same method two times - inside `*ngIf` and inside button `[disabled]` attribute.

My Material dialog:

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
 <p>Insert package name:</p>
  <mat-form-field>
   <mat-label class="font-weight-bold">Package name</mat-label>
   <input matInput #newPackageName>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<ng-container *ngIf="existPackageName(newPackageName.value)">
 <p class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Exist package with same name!!!</p>
</ng-container>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
 <button mat-button class="btn btn-secondary" [mat-dialog-close]="newPackageName.value" cdkFocusInitial [disabled]="existPackageName(newPackageName.value)">Create
 </button>
 <button mat-button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

My Typescript:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'new-package-dialog',
      templateUrl: './new-package/new-package-dialog.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
    })
    export class NewPackageDialog {

      constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {
      }

      onNoClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
      }

      existPackageName(newPackageName: string) {
        return newPackageName.length > 0 && this.data.packages.some(package => package.name === newPackageName);
      }
    }

    export interface DialogData {
      packages: IPackage[];
    }
```

Question: Is there any way to call method `existPackageName(newPackageName.value)` once and pass the result into button `[disabled]` attribute?

Comment: I assume you mean existPackageName, not existFolderName?

Answer (score 1):

You could have in the component:

```
this.shouldDisable = this.existPackageName(this.newPackageName)
```

Then simply:

```
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="newPackageName">
... 
<ng-container *ngIf="shouldDisable">
...
<button [disabled]="shouldDisable" ..rest of the properties>
```

Comment: Attribute of existPackageName() method is passing from html input element. When i use variable on typescript side (your example) i don't know how to pass this variable into method.

Comment: So take the value from `ngModel` of that input element?

Comment: Could you show me this example with ngModel? In code from my question (with two times method calling) when i started write text inside input element validations in two places worked on the fly.

Comment: i added my Typescript code into the question. Your solution is not working in my case.